# PHP EXECUTE PERL w/ agruments

Tags: php, syntax, exec

I have the following php script which needs to call a perl script along with the arguments. If I have the paths correct, is there anything wrong with the syntax? The php and the perl on server side. The php receives information (the $GET['zipc'] thru a url. The perl script will produce an xml file back on the server. I keep getting  unexpected 'exec' (T_STRING) on line 8. Thanks for any advice.

```
<?php
$zipc="-Z";
$lineup="-Y USA";
$fformat="-U";
$duration="-d 2";
$outfile="-o";
$ofile="guide.xml"
exec("perl http://www.myserver.com/myperl.pl" $zipc $_GET['zipc'] $lineup $fformat $duration           $outfile "http://www.myserver.com/myfile.xml");
print"FINALLY GOT TO END";
?>
```

EDIT:
Well I thought it was all worked out. Now I get the following error:
Fatal error: Only variables can be passed

According to the tech support people where I have the scripted hosted, I have to rewrite the line of code that contains the exec so as not to open connections. Kinda at loss on this one. Any advice?

EDIT 2:
The problem lies in the array. From what I understand an array can not be passed as shown in the answer without generating an error. To fix the problem I concatenate the variable and the $_GET into one variable. Seemed to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to [the exec() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) is an **[array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)**. You have multiple syntax errors in your code because you have simply listed a bunch of variables without putting them inside of an array.

Even if `exec()` did take a long list of parameters, *which it doesn't*, your code would still not work because you didn't separate them with commas.

This should work (note the changes on lines 7 & 8):

```
<?php
$zipc="-Z";
$lineup="-Y USA";
$fformat="-U";
$duration="-d 2";
$outfile="-o";
$ofile="guide.xml";
exec("perl http://www.myserver.com/myperl.pl", array($zipc, $_GET['zipc'], $lineup, $fformat, $duration, $outfile, "http://www.myserver.com/myfile.xml"));
print"FINALLY GOT TO END";
```

Comment: I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'exec' (T_STRING) line 8.

Comment: I just noticed you were missing a semicolon on line 7. That has been corrected in my answer.

Comment: ah, ok will check that and see if it helps.